# SQL query to extract a value from records of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, extract, record

How to extract and get the value of records of a column in a table. 
The 'student' table has a column as 'user_ID'. Here are some records of it.

```
 ---------------------
 |    user_ID        |
 ---------------------
 | MPhil/FT/2011/021 |
 | MPhil/PT/2013/023 |
 | MPhil/PT/2012/029 |
 | MPhil/FT/2010/035 |
 ---------------------
```

After 'MPhil/FT' or 'MPhil/PT' the year is given. How to write the SQL query to get the year of user_ID? (Like 2011,2013 etc)

Comment: How is this data stored? Why not store the user_ID in different columns as it seems to me that these information are not relevant.

Comment: These are supposed to be registration numbers of student. The year of registration is added to it. There are other columns in the table. I showed only user_ID column here. What do you mean by different columns? Different columns for each year? I cann't do that because if so i will have to add 2014, 2015,2016 so on.

Comment: a registration date column, as a date, which is trivial to extract the year from.  Or a year column, that contains the year values.

Comment: I want the year to draw a grouped bar chart. And it will not be needed anywhere else in the system. So i think changing the database table to add a column will not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the `SUBSTRING()` & `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` that are available in MySQL.

Or may be you can simple use

```
select LEFT(Right(user_ID,8),4)
```

Comment: How can i print the vlue in PHP? If I wrte the code as `$sql = mysql_query("select LEFT(Right(user_ID,8),4) FROM student") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);` is this correct? And how to print the value in PHP?